# Typescript get distinct values from an object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How do I write `select distinct country, state from myObject` in javascript.

`Array.from(new Set(myObject.map(item => item.country)))` would return distinct countries.. How do I add countries, states and other columns in map???

Input data:

```
const myObject = [
  {
    country: 'USA',
    state: 'Missouri',
    county: 'County1',
  },
  {
    country: 'USA',
    state: 'Missouri',
    county: 'County2',
  },
  {
    country: 'Canada',
    state: 'Alberta',
    county: 'County3',
  },
];
```

To get unique countries, I would write
Array.from(new Set(myObject.map(item => item.country)))
The result would be ['USA', 'Canada']

What should I write if want the result to be

```
[
  {
    country: 'USA',
    state: 'Missouri',
  },
  {
    country: 'Canada',
    state: 'Alberta',
  },
]
```

This contains unique country and state combinations

Comment: could you provide an example of the input data and the expected result? not sure if this is what you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56633869/all-possible-combinations-with-data-from-json-file

Comment: I edited the question with sample data and expected result.

Comment: @diedu I'm not sure why you think this question is not related to TypeScript?

Comment: I updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64345677/2887218) to use your example.  If it does not address your use case, please elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a solution using reduce;

```js
const myObject = [
  { country: 'USA', state: 'Missouri', county: 'County1' },
  { country: 'USA', state: 'Missouri', county: 'County2' },
  { country: 'Canada', state: 'Alberta', county: 'County3' },
];

const unique = myObject.reduce((prev, {country, state}) => 
  prev.some(x => x.country === country && x.state === state )? prev: [...prev, {country, state} ], [])

   console.log(unique )
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code should take an array of objects and a list of keys of those objects, and return an array of objects representing the distinct values for that set of keys.  I assume that the type of properties at those keys will only be `string`, `number`, or `boolean`.

```
function distinct<T extends Record<K, string | number | boolean>,
  K extends keyof T>(arr: T[], ...keys: K[]): Pick<T, K>[] {
  const key = (obj: T) => JSON.stringify(keys.map(k => obj[k]));
  const val = (obj: T) => keys.reduce((a, k) => (a[k] = obj[k], a), {} as Pick<T, K>);
  const dict = arr.reduce((a, t) => (a[key(t)] = val(t), a), {} as { [k: string]: Pick<T, K> })
  return Object.values(dict);
}
```

The idea is to take each object in the array, serialize the tuple of its properties at the keys in question with `JSON.stringify()`, and use this serialized string as a dictionary key.  The value we put at that key is an object consisting of just the values at those properties.  By using a dictionary, we guarantee that only one object will appear for each distinct set of properties at the keys we care about.  Then we turn the values of this dictionary into an array.

If I test it on your `myObject` example, this is what comes out:

```
const result = distinct(myObject, "country", "state");
console.log(result);
/*  [{ "country": "USA", "state": "Missouri" }, { "country": "Canada", "state": "Alberta" }] */
```

which is what you wanted.  Let's also test it on some type and array that I made up now:

```
interface MyObject {
  country: string,
  state: string,
  age: number,
  name: string
}
const arr: MyObject[] = [
  { name: "Alice", age: 35, country: "USA", state: "MA" },
  { name: "Bob", age: 40, country: "USA", state: "MI" },
  { name: "Carmen", age: 35, country: "Mexico", state: "BC" },
  { name: "Danilo", age: 35, country: "Mexico", state: "MI" }
]
```

So we have an array of `MyObject`.  Let's get the distinct `country` values:

```
const distinctCountries = distinct(arr, "country"); // Array<{country: string}>
console.log(distinctCountries); // [{ "country": "USA" }, { "country": "Mexico" }] 
console.log(distinctCountries.map(x => x.country)); // USA, Mexico
```

Notice how what comes out is an array of `{country: string}` values.  You can use `map()` to turn that into just an array of `string`s.  Let's get the distinct `country` and `state` values:

```
const distinctCountriesAndStates = distinct(arr, "country", "state");
console.log(distinctCountriesAndStates);
/* [{ "country": "USA", "state": "MA" }, { "country": "USA", "state": "MI" }, 
{ "country": "Mexico", "state": "BC" }, { "country": "Mexico", "state": "MI" }] */
```

Here it's an array of `{country: string, state: string}` objects.  Not sure how you want to represent those, but you can use `map()` to massage them as you see fit.  Finally let's get the distinct `country` and `age` values:

```
const distinctAgesAndCountries = distinct(arr, "country", "age");
console.log(distinctAgesAndCountries);
/* [{ "country": "USA", "age": 35 }, { "country": "USA", "age": 40 },
 { "country": "Mexico", "age": 35 }] */
```

That's an array of `{country: string, age: number}` objects.

Anyway, hope that gives you some direction.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#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-SCoCAtMYG5KZEAAemIgl8Tg4DEMzbNd0eTt4PvEMVyfDcSyuDQUMUdC4Ew8CANwqiCK6Hp+iIQYiE8RjVQmSYSLI7t2FXIh1x-f5XX4nC8IQ4Sw3IKpX1ISgck0rBoPoWDpNMXMQy3JDpi4tCMKwiCsG0kC0D05ADPzNBfmIgAqciGKo6yaJ7Ts7JXYtS0SEL22YztuxsqKBw-WKNAoqzEsfFTn1g1KQ0rHdRziyiEpYvKL0iwzo3fXcrgC4i1LSDTsKwMMTU88h3K4UCTPaqCQUs0KbLraNkP+VCeL4waoE67kvN64T-KClwstG8KxpNRKk1KjaKqS2jYPGxLm1HLQDoQsKB1Y7a6sQPanka5rOPUxARFlVkgV9ANkm0KznAAcm7IGjW1WrgaldA0DbLgwf+m9lQ7IH3NMABGBHtD3bQkm0AHQuB0HwbzfsgehtBYcZGAsfxxiUbRgAmWmMtxxHAcQVGVCUZAlFpiG305iMJHoV9+aRu8GeA0x4xZzQ3Ac96djQEB5FdAbXKgz6vWgEaEoK2r7LetJpuc5XVf5DRAu0db4uunLkoN-McopqmuDosrsqnbneZSw3Q2FyRXwaxAmqAA)

Comment: Thanks for taking time to explain it in an elaborative way. This works very well for me. And this distinct method accepts dynamic parameters which makes my work very easy as I have to use it for different parameters each time.

Answer (score 1):

Base on referenced answer you can use `Map` and `spread operator` as below

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63274702/4964569

```js
const myObject = [
  { country: 'USA', state: 'Missouri', county: 'County1' },
  { country: 'USA', state: 'Missouri', county: 'County2' },
  { country: 'Canada', state: 'Alberta', county: 'County3' },
];

let data = new Map();

for (let obj of myObject) {
  delete obj.county;
  data.set(obj.country, obj);
}

let unique = [...data.values()];

console.log(unique);
```

Comment: That worked.. Thanks.. But my object has around 60 fields from which I want to consider/map 3 values in one scenario and 8 values in another scenario. Can this be updated to make it more dynamic considering the number of fields I have???

Comment: This solution will not work if you have multiple distinct `country`/`state` pairs.